# Sparse Linux tool C attributes

Tags: gcc

I could find no documentation on the Sparse Linux tool C attributes? There are four - address space, bitwise, force and context. Can you tell me what they are for and what they do?

Answer (score 2):

There is some documentation in `man sparse`.  It isn't much, but it's an ok start.  There is also a bit in the kernel sources, see `Documentation/sparse.txt`.  Also not much there.

I'm pretty sure I've seen more documentation for the sparse attributes somewhere online -- but I can't remember where.  However, I do happen to know a decent, if odd, source of documentation: GCC Bugzilla.  Many sparse features have been requested here, and the bugs contain decent documentation -- usually in the original request, but sometimes elaborated a bit in the ensuing discussion.

- [The bug requesting `address_space`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59850).  This covers `force` as well.  This lets you specify address spaces for pointers, and prevents you from mixing pointers to different address spaces.  The kernel uses this to enforce rules about pointers to process space.  `force` gives you a way to avoid the warnings, and also lets you avoid warnings from some of the other sparse attributes as well.
- [The bug requesting `nocast`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59851).  (Not one you asked for but there you have it.)  This lets you specify that a type shouldn't be subject to implicit conversion.
- [The bug requesting `bitwise`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59852).  This lets you say that an integral type must be treated "bitwise" -- that mathematical, as opposed to logical, operations on it are not well-defined.  This is handy if you are dealing with "wrong-endian" values, for example.
- [The bug requesting `context`](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59856).  This is the most complicated attribute.  It is for automatic checking of some kinds of locking invariants.